# Calling a `REST` service that runs on `EKS` from a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

I host in `EKS` a container with `API` that is exposed by a `service` object.
The service is exposed as `ALB`. It has an endpoint and a service account with attached token for external access.
I manage to call it using `curl` and `postman` (After settings service account, roles etc.)
I would like to call it from a lambda function (That will support token setting just like postman allows).
What is the easiest way to do so?